# How to do what GPGTools's context menu does, but using GPG in the command line?

Tags: encryption, command-line, gnupg, pgp

I use Mac and sometimes I use GPGTools to do the following:

1. open the TextEdit application and write, let's say, "Hello World" there.
2. select "Hello World" and control-click the selection, to open a context menu.
3. in the context menu, select "Services > OpenPGP: Encrypt Selection to New Window" and select the recipients in the dialog box that appears.

Then a new window pops up, showing an encrypted message that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

hQEMA0cwf/w1ZfpTAQf/Ze9lwDIlewAHXz2t7UgM/CJGB1E1UCHejJF21nSunztI
yf7LRMxb20VvXa6VbrzgObBrlgHS9noKCmgS9CtdXMf1owjXUbZjmFmXlIfxQnuR
**[...]**
Wuqxb83MWOBVzZ2fXKettmb39NfMBR9zEPICiMd48DBvUlR3l3aaptusjRYr865B
9em2G3bK050Y/rT3Dz6WhqNT9m70ePXefM49sjruUPrQwLi9yS+CcV4dfayBgCQD
iT5be+E=
=jqRq
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

I would like to be able to do the same thing using the command line. And I would like to know how to do that in a way that is independent of the operating system. The solution should work in Windows and Linux too.

I know that GPGTools is based on GPG (GnuPG) and, therefore, I would assume that it should be possible to achieve what I want using the "gpg" command line tool. I know how to use "gpg" to encrypt, for instance, a "file.txt" file and obtain an encrypted "file.txt.gpg" file, but this encrypted file doesn't contain a "PGP MESSAGE" as shown above.

In summary, my question is: how can I encrypt a text string (not a file) and obtain a "PGP MESSAGE", using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encrypt a string via standard input you would do this:

```
$ gpg --encrypt --armor --hidden-recipient "your_key@address.here" --output -
```

After executing this command it will appear to hang. Go ahead and type (copy/paste) your string.

```
Pasted string goes here.
Hitting enter creates a new line.
Backspace deletes characters.
You get the idea.
```

Now press [Enter] to create a new line. Then hit [CTRL+D] (this signals "end-of-file") to terminate the program.

`gpg` will then dump your ASCII armored encrypted text directly to the shell:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

hQEMAwAAAAAAAAAAAQf7BlN7eYqI3lzZS9soEOEXAMPLEIbTkS8mHYMQ68/WXWVw
QRhF5eNjOS3+9VgKU44I/D7pQ53IOTBC/ABPLp9Ykfi9qDNabw6YFob7HGrT9yN9
/zrpAFztREVpgTLfMVdqOIphCx+A9jk/p9D1nRrGkXlCtRpQw9ho/larlQEPyaEx
hK8TOaoELOrIF1D98KEXAMPLEKRLGmGEncR7Vd5DuTXo62Bs3UZYjVYNaboFwZxS
m0+6gLp2JBMc/Gg1/Llk9ufDEci7Vwd+udvPoGPfpbiIGhp2bOnjN03TEbDenu59
219q03bIrQhGmpbuXs7A3lc80v60BTNJpfXVEXAMPLEhAV8P2G4t9en3oIbXl9nH
rpWObJFCCoeWjtZzwammzzVRzMnQjzKyyQUFF8/FfEut/NkKhxfqXWuW2lsvzChC
5OUQjt+dFSGG3NdMFKuoUco+zECH8XgbO9AkC45fJE5Akg==
=6yVB
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

**Side note:**

If you are using OS X it is also possible to paste text directly from the pasteboard buffer using `pbpaste`. You can pipe its output into `gpg` by doing this instead:

```
$ pbpaste | gpg --encrypt --armor --hidden-recipient "your_key@address.here" --output -
```

Just be aware that the pasteboard buffer is not cleared automatically. If you copy a secret string there, be sure to copy something else (random irrelevant text) to clear it when you're done. Anyone (an attacker) with access to your account via `ssh` or other means could, for example, read your plain-text secret without any effort whatsoever.

To simply clear the pasteboard buffer via the shell, do: `echo | pbcopy`